# Javascript strtotime formatting for non-specific dates

Tags: javascript, date, time

I need help with some Javascript strtotime-type code, please.

Our company runs a weekly promotion for 2 days only for its members. So when a member logs in, they see a banner promoting the promotion. If they happen to login outside of the promotion dates, the banner links to an information page. Otherwise, it links directly to the promotion.

Currently we're updating this by hand each week, which is a pain. We'd like to be able to use Javascript* to automatically change the link for us. OK, no problem, right?

Well, the thing is, what we don't want to have to do is go in and edit the script every week with the specific dates/times -- otherwise, what's the point? Currently the promotion runs Wednesday at 9a.m. to Thursday at 9a.m. It changes from time to time, every couple of months or so (Mon-Tue, 9a-9p, that sort of thing) so we will have to edit the script from time to time, but if we can avoid doing it weekly, that'd be great.

So here's what I came up with. It's heavily commented so my not-so-technical co-workers can go in and make the edits without too much difficulty.

```
var getData = function(){

    var d = new Date();
    var today = d.getDay(); // current day, numerically
    var hr = d.getHours(); // current hour

    // For Days:
    // 0 = Sunday
    // 1 = Monday
    // 2 = Tuesday
    // 3 = Wednesday
    // 4 = Thursday
    // 5 = Friday
    // 6 = Saturday

    var startDay = 3;
    var endDay = 4;

    // For Hours:
    // This is a 24-hour clock. Midnight (12:00 AM) is 0, Noon = 12, 9 PM = 21, etc.
    // So for a start time of 9 AM, put 9, and for an end time of 9 PM, put 21.

    var startTime = 12;
    var endTime = 15;

    // Set the "url" variable to the NON-sale landing page. Put the SALE page URL in
    // the "url" variables within the nested "if" statements below:

    var url = 'http://link-to-the-non-promo-info-page';

    if (( today >= startDay ) && ( hr >= startTime )) {
        if ( today <= endDay ) && ( hr <= endTime )) {
            url = 'http://link-to-the-live-promotion';
        }
    }

    // ... non-essential variables and the actual display code 
    // below this line...
    // ...
}
```

Notice I set the vars so that the promo runs 12p-3pm. If this were the real thing, the desired result would be for the promo link to display Wednesday 12pm to Thursday 3pm. What happens with this code, obviously, is that the promo banner is live Wednesday 12-3 and then Thursday 12-3.

I've goofed around with various permutations of the logic and haven't been able to hit the right one. Ultimately, I'd like to be able to open the script (or for one of my co-workers to open it), and be able to set the start day/time and end day/time, without having to set specific dates (Wednesday, July 24 to Thursday, July 25) and it just work.

If this were PHP I'd have it wrapped up. But it's Javascript, so any assistance I can get making this work would be fantastic.

Thanks,
Bob

**UPDATE**: @Kamala, I tweaked the time a bit by adding minutes, and a few other tweaks, but there's an issue of it not accepting the end time. Note that the script is set so that the start and end day is today, and the start/end times are now past (for EST zone, anyway) but the promo link is still being displayed:

```
    var d = new Date();
var today = d.getDay(); // current day, numerically
var hr = d.getHours(); // current hour
var mn = d.getMinutes();
if (mn < 10) {
    mn = "0"+mn;
}
var time = hr+":"+mn;

// For Days:
// 0 = Sunday
// 1 = Monday
// 2 = Tuesday
// 3 = Wednesday
// 4 = Thursday
// 5 = Friday
// 6 = Saturday

var startDay = 5;
var endDay = 5;

// For Hours:
// This is a 24-hour clock. Midnight (12:00 AM) is 0, Noon = 12, 9 PM = 21, etc.
// So for a start time of 9 AM, put 9, and for an end time of 9 PM, put 21.

var startTime = "11:00";
var endTime = "12:00";

// Set the "url" variable to the NON-sale landing page. Put the SALE page URL in
// the "url" variables within the nested "if" statements below:

var url1 = 'http://info-landing-page';


if (( today >= startDay ) && ( today <= endDay ) ) { // Awesome, we're within the promo days
    if ( ( today != startDay && today != endDay ) // The promo is in full-swing - doesn't matter what time it is
        || ( today == startDay && time >= startTime )
        || ( today == endDay && time <= endTime ) ) {

        url1 = 'http://promo-url';
        alert("promo url set");
    }
 } else {
     alert("we're pointing to the LP");
 }
```

Is additional logic needed? Another nested "if" perhaps? I'm lost.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: With this running in client-side javascript, you're using the time zone of the user to determine the promotion time.  So a user on the other side of the world could get the "afternoon" promo in the middle of your "night".  Also, they could hack this very easily, or just bookmark the promo url.  Are you ok with that?

Comment: Hmm. Didn't think about the time zone issue. Thanks for the head's up. I'm not too concerned about the other -- the actual programming behind the promo page populates the page at the proper times based on Eastern Standard Time. So if a user hits that page, they just get a page with no items. Not a huge deal, we're just trying to avoid having them hit the page and finding nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
if (( today >= startDay ) && ( today <= endDay ) ) { // Awesome, we're within the promo days
    if( ( today != startDay && today != endDay )  // The promo is in full-swing - doesn't matter what time it is
        ||( today == startDay && hr >= startTime ) 
        || (today == endDay && hr <= endTime ) )
        url = 'http://link-to-the-live-promotion';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need are two checks. If the promo's on day 1, is it after a certain time? Or if it's on day 2, is it before a certain time?

```
if ( today === startDay  &&  hr >== startTime ) {
    url = 'http://link-to-the-live-promotion';
} else if ( today === endDay  &&  hr <== endTime ) {
    url = 'http://link-to-the-live-promotion';
}
```

For your problem, there are no days in between the two days.. no need to check if `day > startDay && day < endDay`.

EDIT: Well, you probably want that capability in case your promo ever goes to 3 days. Here's another try handling this (rewritten to use OR's instead of if-else-if's:

```
if ((today > startDay  &&  today < endDay) ||
   (today == startDay  &&  hr >= startTime) ||
   (today == endDay  &&  hr <= endTime)) {
    url = 'http://link-to-the-live-promotion';
}
```

Comment: Yep, definitely want that flexibility! Thanks!